# Authenticate returns None with correct username and password during Userlogin

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates, django-login

My User login has some issue with the authentication process.
I am using Django 1.9 and Python 3.6

[this is my code repository](https://github.com/bikirandas/LiquorStore)

> user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

Returns user as none

This is how my **Accounts/views.py** looks for login

```
def register(request):
registered = False
if request.method == 'POST':
    reg_form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)
    if reg_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = reg_form.save()
        # print('before set password = ', user.password)
        user.set_password(user.password)
        # print('after set password = ', user.password)
        user.save()
        print(user.password)
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.email = user.email
        profile.first_name = user.first_name
        profile.last_name = user.last_name
        if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
            profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
            print('uploading pic .....')
        profile.save()
        args = {'reg_form': reg_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': True}
        head_list.update(args)
        return render(request, 'registration.html', head_list)

    else:
        print(reg_form.errors, profile_form.errors)
        args = {'reg_form': reg_form.errors, 'profile_form': profile_form.errors, 'registered': False}
        head_list.update(args)
        return render(request, 'registration.html', head_list, args)
else:
    reg_form = RegistrationForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()
    args = {'reg_form': reg_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': False}
    head_list.update(args)
    print(head_list)
    return render(request, 'registration.html', head_list)


def login_view(request):
params = {}
params.update(csrf(request))
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        # First get the username and password supplied
        # username = request.POST.get('username', '')
        # password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        # Django's built-in authentication function:
        print(username, password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print('after aunthenticate', user)
    # If we have a user
        if user:
            # Check it the account is active
            if user.is_active:
                # Log the user in.
                login(request, username)
                # Send the user back to some page.
                # In this case their homepage.
                # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('/user_login/'))
                return render_to_response('user_login.html', RequestContext(request, {}))
            else:
                # If account is not active:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is not active.")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed.")
            print("They used username: {} and password: {}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

else:
    form = LoginForm()
    args = {'form': form}
    head_list.update(args)
    # Nothing has been provided for username or password.
    return render(request, 'login.html', head_list)
```

The login.html page is shown below

```
{% block content %}
    <section class="container">
    <h1>LiquorApp Login Console</h1>
        <div class="login">
            <h1>Login to WebApp</h1>
            <form method="post" action="/user_login/">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% comment %}Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />
                <br />{% endcomment %}
                {% comment %}<p><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" placeholder="username"></p>
                <p><input id ="password" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="password"></p>
                <p class="remember_me">{% endcomment %}
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
                    Remember me on this computer
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Please suggest where am I doing it wrong that my authenticate module is returning none.

I have also added the following in the settings.py file

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

Comment: Django comes with [built in authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views), including a login view. You should use it rather than writing your own. Note that Django 1.9 is end of life and does not receive security fixes any more. Upgrade to the latest 1.11 LTS.

Comment: Note that you might not be setting the password correctly when users register. Try creating a superuser with `manage.py createsuperuser` and see whether you can log in as that user.

Comment: @Alasdair i have tried to login with superuser i created. but it gives a different error.

Comment: @Alasdair Using the django built in login i am able to render to userlogin page but it doesnot authenticate it properly since my user name doesnot get populated for non-superusers.

Comment: Setting `user.set_password(user.password)` looks wrong. You are setting the password to the hashed value. I would try removing that line.

Comment: i have updated to django 1.11.4 and still issue remains can you please suggest something that can help me to authenticate the user successfully with current functions

Comment: let me try removing the set_password

Comment: I can't help you debug the login view -- you should just use the Django one instead.

Comment: thanks the authenticate is now returning the username. but now it fails at login(request, username)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
user.set_password(user.password)
```

from Accounts.views.register

Answer (score 5):

Django 2.1 authentication returns **users** for any authentication, only if **user.is_active=TRUE** and you need to first save the response of **form.save(commit=False)** and then set custom variables

```
if form.is_valid():
    user= form.save(commit=False)
    user.active=True
    user.staff=False
    user.admin=False
    user.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully')
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define check_password for your User class

```
def check_password(self, raw_password):
    if self.password == raw_password:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Because if you check the source code under django.contrib.auth.models,
check_password() raise and NotImplemented error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `user.is_active is True` before calling `authenticate(username=user.username, password=password, request=request)` in Django 1.11.

It worked fine in Django 1.8, but somewhere between LTS 1.8 and LTS 1.11 they added an additional check for `user.is_active` in `ModelBackend` class:

```
class ModelBackend(object):
    """
    Authenticates against settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
    """

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a non-existing user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user

    def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        """
        Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
        that attribute are allowed.
        """
        is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
        return is_active or is_active is None
```

As for the recommendation to use Django built-in auth views, they are not handy for customized non-standard authentication.