# Cant login using hashed password in django

Tags: django, forms-authentication

I am trying to implement a custom user model. Whenever I try to log in for a user (created using the registration form), it returns no user.
but if I create a user using the admin panel then the login function works perfectly.

I think the problem is with password hashing. Tried some solve from here and there but seems like I can't find what I am looking for.

The problem I am having :
email: yeamin21@outlook.com
pass: 1234 works (created using admin panel)
but, email: yeamin21@outlook.com
pass: hashed(1234) does not (created using the registration form)

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import transaction
from Customer.models import User, Restaurant

class RestaurantSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = User
        fields = ['email','name','username']
    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_restaurant=True
        user.is_active=True
        user.save()
        restaurant = Restaurant.objects.create(user=user)
        restaurant.save()
        return user
```

**backend.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend, ModelBackend
from Customer.models import User


class CustomBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self,email=None,password=None):
        try:
            user=User.objects.get(email=email)
            print('active')
            if user.check_password(password) is True:
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return User.objects.get(email=User.email)

    def get_user(self, email):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from Customer.forms import RestaurantSignUpForm
from Customer.models import User



def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("Logged in")
        else:
            print(user)
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed
thanks to this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971226/10602634

```
def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
    try:
        user= User.objects.get(email=email)
        if check_password(password, user.password):
            return user
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```